# SQLCE 4 Private Deployment Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am trying to privately deploy SQL CE WPF with Entity Framework 6 using Code First.

On Development machine database generates fine in AppData folder and all works fine however on Testing PC I get an exception (no db):

```
"The ADO.NET provide with invariant name 'System.Data.SQlServerCe.40' is either not registered in the machine or application config file'
```

I've tried to implement all available literature regarding this issue but still has a problem. I've checked the Bin folder with Deployed Folder and it is the same, all libraries (x86 and amd64) are present and Project Platform target is x86.

1. [No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821284/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name)
2. http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html
3. [Entity Framewok Code First "ADO.NET provider not found" with local SQL Server CE DLL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575582/entity-framewok-code-first-ado-net-provider-not-found-with-local-sql-server-ce)

Bellow is my App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>

  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="MyProject.DAL.GreatContext, MyProject">
        <databaseInitializer type="MyProject.Module.Database.Dal.GreatDbInitializer, MyProject" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0"
           invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
           description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact"
           type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>


</configuration>
```

I also have added the bellow code but still issue remains :

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the assembly version of the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll included with your project?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use version 4,0,0,1 of the ado.net provider, you need to use this assembly redirect:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Redirecting Entityframework.dll will not work.

And the proper solution is to use my EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.PrivateDeployment NuGet package

Comment: Hi Erik, I;ve tried that code also, and got the exception "The located assembly s manifest definition does not match the assebmly reference" on the Development pc.

Comment: Are you using assembly version 4,0,0,1? Some tips here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference

Comment: System.Data.SqlServerCe : Version 4.0.0.0, pls advice if I should upgrade ? I've added them through Nuget

Comment: Remove any assembly redirects, then, and make sure the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll reference is set to Copy local and Copy always

Comment: Hmm.. not sure what you mean by assembly redirects. I think this already done via nuget installer? in fact I can see that System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll is set to Copy Locak and I've checked taht System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll exist on Testing pc ...

Comment: And what happened then? (I will update/reissue my blog post...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63187/discussion-between-erikej-and-jim).

Comment: I had the same issue and commenting this line out fixed it for SqlCe 3.5

    <!--<bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>-->